# error: Multiple top-level packages discovered in a flat-layout when creating docker image

Tags: python, docker, pip

I'm trying to create a docker image which uses the package PyClaw within Clawpack. My Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM python:3.10-slim

RUN pip install numpy matplotlib
RUN pip install --user clawpack==5.9.0
```

I have no issues installing numpy or matplotlib, but the clawpack install gives this error:

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.

3.857   │ exit code: 1

3.857   ╰─> [14 lines of output]

3.857       error: Multiple top-level packages discovered in a flat-layout: ['pyclaw', 'riemann', 'geoclaw', 'amrclaw', 'visclaw', 'classic', 'clawutil', 'clawpack'].

3.857       To avoid accidental inclusion of unwanted files or directories,

3.857       setuptools will not proceed with this build.

3.857       If you are trying to create a single distribution with multiple packages

3.857       on purpose, you should not rely on automatic discovery.

3.857       Instead, consider the following options:

3.857       1. set up custom discovery (`find` directive with `include` or `exclude`)

3.857       2. use a `src-layout`

3.857       3. explicitly set `py_modules` or `packages` with a list of names

3.857       To find more information, look for "package discovery" on setuptools docs.

3.857       [end of output]

Is there a way to modify my Dockerfile to fix this issue? I am a beginner to Docker images and do not understand much of the endless jargon which surrounds this stuff.

Comment: https://github.com/clawpack/clawpack/issues/211 It seems the code was fixed in https://github.com/clawpack/clawpack/pull/212 but not yet released. Install from Github.